# How can i return value from one method to another & swapping

Tags: java, return-value, swap

I have this

```
public class Mapper implements ScramblerIF
{
 private static String map = "drsjckpwrypwsftylmzxopqtdo";

public static String charAt(String str) 
{
 //char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
int length = str.length();

 for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
{
 char aChar = str.charAt(i);
 char upper = Character.toUpperCase(aChar);
 int num = (upper - 'A');
char mChar = map.charAt(num);
 //String chard = Character.toString(mChar);

 StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( str);
   buf.setCharAt( i, mChar );
 }
   return str;
 }

public String scramble(String str) {
return charAt(str);
 }
}
```

I am trying to get it to where the method

```
 public String scramble(String str) {
return charAt(str);
 }
```

returns the computed value from the

```
 public static String charAt(String str)
```

method. Don't know where i went wrong.

Also instead of using

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer( str);
   buf.setCharAt( i, mChar );
```

how would i be able to use the swap function?
When I try

```
 char temp = chars[i];
chars[i] = chars[mChar];
chars[mChar] = temp;
```

I am given an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Summary of what i am trying to do is "For each character in the original string, use its position in the alphabet to look up its replacement in the map string. For example, the string “dog” would be translated to “jtp”."

Comment: The problem is not in returning a return value of another method. Could you post the stack-trace of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Does your string contain non-alphabetical characters?

Comment: how would i go about doing that? sorry kinda slow to this

Comment: I sure hope you don't have that string `map` in your actual code. It would be interesting to see how you decode a message where 2 values could be encoded to `w` and 3 values to `p`'s ;)

Answer (score 1):

This scrables with the *replacement-map* you have provided. It also handles **upper and lower** case letters:

```
public class Mapper {
    //                           abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    private static String map = "drsjckpwrypwsftylmzxopqtdo";

    public static String scramble(String str) {

        if (!str.matches("[A-Za-z]*"))
            throw new RuntimeException(str + " contains weird characters");

        String out = "";
        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                out += Character.toUpperCase(map.charAt(c - 'A'));
            } else {
                out += map.charAt(c - 'a');
            }
        }

        return out;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(scramble("David"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `%` makes it asymmetric.

Comment: Yes, I added that in the comment some seconds ago! ;)

Comment: @khachik: added check that no characters are "weird"!

Comment: Thank you this is exacly what i need to be outputted. The only difference will be ill be taking the user input from another class. Then returning this to the tester

Answer (score 0):

StringBuffer.setCharAt() will throw an exception if you try to set a character beyond the buffer. You haven't put anything in the buffer.

In addition, take a look at when you are creating the buffer.

Comment: how would i put something in the buffer?

Comment: The first step is to look at the class documentation -- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html. Take a look at the "append" methods.